# Palindrome using shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have tried to write a code for checking a string if it is a palidrome but dont know where am I going wrong

```
read a
len=`echo $a|wc -m`
len=`expr $len - 1`
# echo $len
flag=1
for((i=0;i<len/2;i++))
do
    k=`expr $len - $i - 1`
    # echo "${a:$i:1} ${a:$k:1}"
    if((${a:$i:1} != ${a:$k:1}))
    then    
        flag=0 
        break
    fi

done

if(($flag == 1))
then
    echo Palindrome
else
    echo Not Palindrome
fi
```

Comment: Your code works for me. What problem are you having?

Comment: Please run your code through http://shellcheck.net.

Comment: I feel like `if [[ "${a:$i:1}" != "${a:$k:1}" ]]` would be the way to go here. Although you could just knock this whole thing out with something like `[ "$(echo ${a// /} | rev)" == "${a// /}" ]] && echo "Palindrome" || echo "Not Palindrome"`

Comment: `(( ))` does arithmetic operations (including comparisons), not string/character comparisons, so the `if((${a:$i:1} != ${a:$k:1}))` is not doing what you think it is. I also second chepner's recommendation of [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) for pointing out a bunch of other bad practices in the script.

Comment: @Zain : If you are on Linux, you should have `rev` available. In this case, `ìf [[ $a == $(rev <<<$a) ]]` would be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you have used `((..))` instead of `[[ .. ]]` for the string comparison (spacing matters in the latter).

- You can get length directly with `${#a}`.
- Your algorithm starts from both ends and then increments/decrements towards the middle. So you can get `flag` implicitly - if you pass the midpoint, the string is a palindrome.
- You can replace all use of `expr` with `(( .. ))`.
- `for ((..))` allows initialising/updating multiple variables.

```
read a

for (( i=0, k=${#a}-1; i<=k; i++, k-- ))
do
    [[ ${a:$i:1} != ${a:$k:1} ]] && break
done

if (( i>k ))
then
    echo Palindrome
else
    echo Not Palindrome
fi
```